# Unity 5.3 non-generic type error with WeakReference

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm using Unity 5.3.5f1 with Visual Studio Community 2015 and I keep getting the error: "The non-generic type `System.WeakReference' cannot be used with the type arguments" when I try to use a WeakReference with generics. I know that it is supported from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg712738(v=vs.110).aspx).

Snippet of my code:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;

namespace aim4.util
{
 /** The initial ID */
    private int initId;
    /** The next ID */
    private int nextId;
    /** A mapping from IDs to weak references of objects */
    private SortedDictionary<int, WeakReference<T>> idToObj =
      new SortedDictionary<int, WeakReference<T>>();
```

I have a feeling its related to Unity because if I load the script in VS outside of the project then it doesn't complain. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Rule of thumbs: If it works in VS with latest .NET FW but not in Unity (mono, .NET v2.0) it's either a bug or an implementation detail. You need to workaround either way

Comment: @Mark You're right. A workaround I found was to actually get the source online and then just add it to my Unity project. Is this really bad practice? I have to re-code this from Java and there are lots of dependencies and so I really don't want to change too much, which is why I resorted to that. Also, is it possible to mark your comment as an answer?

Comment: No, but I copy-pasted it as an answer, also extended as of your comment. Thanks!

Comment: If you have not done it yet, install [Unity tools for Visual Studio](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/features/unitytools-vs.aspx) it will allow you to set the target framework to "Unity 3.5 full base class libraries", that will remove from intellesense classes you are not allowed to use like `WeakRefrence<T>` (note, if you are using a "unity project" instead of a normal .csproj file you can't open the property page to change the target framework, but it defaults to the specal target already)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*[converting comment to answer]*
Rule of thumbs: If it works in VS with latest .NET FW but not in Unity (mono, .NET v2.0) it's either a bug or an implementation detail. You need to workaround either way.

As of your question in comment. Porting to Unity from a Java project most probably will be a challenge. You better prepare to bump into issues of the kind. In which case you either have to workaround again, or refactor.
For that, I wouldn't recommend "hacking things" into the engine (like what you mention, the mono source code for WeakReference).
It might work but if and when it's not, you can't get any help neither from Unity nor here as you've just built your very own and unique framework. Long story short (IMHO) it'll backfire sooner or later.

Unity is a game engine, so the Mono/.NET behind is just for scripting, not for full scale OO programming. The reason is, in game engines most items you create are self-contained, living in their own little bubble, not robust applications serving a single purpose.
You can make class hierarchies, abstractions, nest and seal etc "on a level" but there are serious (and logical) limitations on that as this kind of 'implementation detail' is not important for a game engine.

So, again, if you bump into a problem workaround (i.e. get rid of WeakReference and find out why it was originally important to "early GC" the particular object) or refactor (think through what would work in a game engine for the purpose coded in Java).

Hope this helps!
Cheers!

Comment: Thanks. I suppose I'm being a bit naive but it is for a relatively small simulation and not a full scale game.  But yes, I'll keep in mind everything you mentioned.

Comment: @Amposter If it's a small project I would refactor (sounds faster) and keep only the math it runs. Whatever your decision will be, good luck with it

Answer (score 1):

`WeakReference` is indeed generic. However, it looks like you are using it with type `T`, not an actual type in your code.

Try replacing `T` with the actual type you want to use. For example:

```
private SortedDictionary<int, WeakReference<GameObject>> idToObj =
  new SortedDictionary<int, WeakReference<GameObject>>();
```

---

It appears that there is a [non-generic version](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.weakreference(v=vs.110).aspx) too.

You should use this without type arguments and then use casting to get the type you want:

```
private SortedDictionary<int, WeakReference> idToObj =
  new SortedDictionary<int, WeakReference>();

var obj = idToObj[0].Target as GameObject;

if (obj)
{
    // Do stuff... 
}
```

Comment: Nope. Tried that but it doesn't work. It's not recognizing that the class exists for some reason, the class doesn't show when I check the list of scripts under 'System'.

Comment: It seems that Unity is using the non-generic version: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.weakreference(v=vs.110).aspx. You will need to cast from `object` to the type you want.